# Java compiler throws 'might not have been initialized' error incorrectly?

Tags: java, javac

Here's a sample method:

```
boolean method(int value, boolean check1, boolean check2) {
    String code;
    boolean valueIncorrect = false;
    boolean otherIncorrect = false;

    if (value < 0 || value > 10) {
        code = "lengthCode";
        valueIncorrect = true;
    }
    if (check1) {
        code = "otherCode";
        otherIncorrect = true;
    } else if (check2) {
        code = "otherCode";
        otherIncorrect = true;
    }

    if(!valueIncorrect && !otherIncorrect) {
        return true;
    }
    
    if (otherIncorrect) {
        return code.contains("HELLO");
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the error: `variable code might not have been initialized` at the line where I try to call the contains() method.
If we look at the logic, it's impossible for code to be null at that point, right? Or am I tripping? Execution will only reach that point if one of the booleans is true, and wherever either of them is being set to true, the value of code is also being set.
So I don't expect an infinitely complex level of analysis by the compiler, but I also know that if it was a much simpler condition:

```
if(boolean) code = "x";
else code = "y";
return code.contains("whatever");
```

like this would not throw an error. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: There might be a logical path in the method where `code` has not been defined, but then you call `contains()` on it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is no such path. To call `code.contains()`, the variable `otherIncorrect` must be true. In all the places where `otherIncorrect` is set to true, the value for code is also initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that since you can infer that `code` will always be initialized, the Java compiler can (and should) make the same inferences and call your code correct.

In fact, the compiler is applying the definite assignment rules set out in the JLS rules in the [16: Definite Assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-16.html) chapter.  These rules do not allow (for example) the values of conditions to be taken into account *unless* they are (compile time) *constant expressions* ... in the technical sense defined by the JLS.

A conformant compiler is required to implement those rules literally.  It is **not acceptable** for a clever Java compiler to (say) use the latest machine reasoning technology and deduce that `code` will in fact always be initialized before use.

Why?  Because that leads to portability problems; i.e. one Java compiler calls your source code erroneous and another one says it is correct.

---

In short, it is not a Java compiler error.  It is a feature of the Java language.

Comment: That makes sense. What is the philosophy behind a 'possible non init' being an error, as opposed to a warning? Especially since it does not attempt to be an accurate judge of correctness?

Comment: The philosophy is that it is attempting to project programmers from a common class of errors that (in other programming languages) can lead to runtime errors.  For example, in Python if you refer to a variable before it has been initialised you will get an exception.  In C or C++ you will get unspecified behavior.

Comment: It is unfortunate that there is a relatively small subset of Java programs where the "may not have been assigned" is a false positive.  But you can always work around that; e.g. by adding a (logically redundant) assignment or initialization expression.

Comment: Yes the 'fix' for this is trivial in all false positive cases. It's interesting that this is one class of potential runtime errors that the language refuses to allow at all but not others. Perhaps because it is easy to detect a large chunk of this error class at compile time

Comment: It is moot.  Even fixing the spec to *allow* a compiler to be smart would introduce problems.  And besides, there are lots of examples where a "smart" compiler would have difficulty.  Even in the 2020's undirected code correctness proving is a hard problem ... especially when you need to do it every time you compile a class.  Seriously, this is a minor inconvenience for programmers, not something that warrants throwing lots of R&D effort at.

Comment: @HiJonk actually, the reason it works this way is that zeroing out a variable has a cost associated. It's small, but non-zero. And the JVM indeed _does not_ zero out declared variables. The value of that variable before you assign anything to it is whatever random garbage was in memory. The class verifier will therefore _reject_ any class files that have been hacked to allow access-before-write, as that's a potential security risk (maybe there's part of a password in there or something).

Comment: @rzwitserloot - I hadn't thought of the verifier aspect.  But (wearing my language lawyer hat) while that may have partly *motivated* the original language design decision, the decision stands on its own.  If (hypothetically) the JLS allowed smart compilers to ignore Chapter 16 rules (when safe), it would be simple to write said compilers to silently inject redundant bytecodes to initialize the variable anyway ... to make life easier for the verifier.  And (hypothetically) the JIT compiler optimizer could optimize away any redundant native instructions for the redundant initialization.

Comment: @StephenC it's incompatible with how fields work, which _are_ zeroed out. The choice was (presumably) made because attempting to track read-before-write for fields is too difficult. If language design was the primary reason, this hybrid 'fields no, locals yes' model is nuts. JIT _does_ eliminate redundant instructions. For example, `list.toArray(new String[0])` is faster than `list.toArray(new String[list.size()])`, because the latter has to zero out first, the former skips that step.

Comment: You misunderstood what I am saying.  The hybrid 'fields no, locals yes' would not be nuts in the scenario that the JLS allowed "maybe not initialized" but not "definitely not initialized" and added an implicit initialization in the latter case.  Anyway, my real point is that the definite assignment rule makes sense **irrespective** of the bytecodes and runtime overheads of unnecessary initialization.  And I DON'T think they specified it that way in the JLS because of efficiency considerations related to redundant initialization.

Comment: (Above ... I mean "former case" rather that "latter case".)  Efficiency was not what Java 1.0 / 1.1 were about!   They were far more concerned with making it easy to write reliable and portable code than with writing fast code.  You wanted fast, you used C or C++.  (Java didn't have a JIT compiler to start with.  Or a verifier ... AFAIK.)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you're right as the top if/if/else-if passes through without getting hit, both are false, and it will return true early in the next statement before that.

That's very indirect though and I don't think the compiler will infer something like that.